# How can I vectorize this PyTorch snippet?

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization

My pytorch code is running too slow due to it not being vectorized and I am unsure how to go about vectorizing it as I am relatively new to PyTorch. Can someone help me do this or point me in the right direction?

```
level_stride = 8
loc = torch.zeros(H * W, 2)
for i in range(H):
   for j in range(W):
       loc[i * H + j][0] = level_stride * (j + 0.5)
       loc[i * H + j][1] = level_stride * (i + 0.5)
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but the above code wouldn't work. I think there is a problem with your indexing, resulting in a `IndexError`. Perhaps your index calculation was supposed to be `i * W + j`.  
I'm about to write an answer to your actual question, and presuming `i * W + j` to be the correct one in it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you defined the tensor to be of size `(H*W, 2)`. This is of course entirely optional, but it might be more expressive to preserve the dimensionality explicitly, by having `H` and `W` be separate dimension in the tensor.  That makes some operations later on easier as well.

The values you compute to fill the tensor with originate from ranges. We can use the `torch.arange` function to get the same ranges, already in form of a tensor, ready to be put into your `loc` tensor.  If that is done, you could see it as, completely leaving out the for loops, and just treating `j` and `i` as different tensors.
If you're not familiar with tensors, this might seem confusing, but operations between single number values and tensors work just as well, so not much of the rest of the code has to be changed.

I'll give you a expression of how your code could look like with these changes applied:

```py
level_stride = 8
loc = torch.zeros(H, W, 2)
j = torch.arange(W).expand((H, W))
loc[:, :, 0] = level_stride * (j + 0.5)
i = torch.arange(H).expand((W, H)).T
loc[:,:,1] = level_stride * (i + 0.5)
```

The most notable changes are the assignments to `j` and `i`, and the usage of slicing to fill the data into `loc`.
For completeness, let's go over the expressions that are assigned to `i` and `j`.

`j` starts as a `torch.arange(W)` which is just like a regular range, just in form of a tensor. Then `.expand` is applied, which you could see as the tensor being repeated. For example, if `H` had been 5 and `W` 2, then a range of 2 would have been created, and expanded to a size of `(5, 2)`. The size of this tensor thereby matches the first two sizes in the `loc` tensor.

`i` starts just the same, only that `W` and `H` swap positions. This is due to i originating from a range based on `H` rather then `W`.  Notable here is that `.T` is applied at the end of that expression. The reason for this is that the `i` tensor still has to match the first two dimensions of `loc`. `.T` transposes the tensor for this reason.

If you have a subject specific reason to have the `loc` tensor in the `(H*W, 2)` shape, but are otherwise happy with this solution, you could reshape the tensor in the end with `loc.reshape(H*W,2)`.

Comment: Is there anything left unclear?